# Complexity of Symbolic Matrix Multiplication

Tags: matrices, computational-complexity, symbolic-computation

I am not sure if this is the right community in which to ask this question, but I'm trying to understand symbolic matrix math better, and cannot find many resources about it online.

Specifically, does anyone know the complexity of the algorithms which perform symbolic matrix multiplications in packages such as Mathematica, Matlab, and Sympy? If not, can you speculate on their performance vs. normal matrix multiplication?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The complexity obviously depends on the elements of the matrices involved. It's not a concern when doing numerical computations, as one usually assumes the basic operation ([fused multiply-add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation)) takes constant time. By the way, MATLAB does numeric computations (but the MuPad toolbox does symbolics computations).

Comment: **Speculation** about the performance of specific computer algebra systems is outside the scope of MSE.  I hope my answer to your question is of use.

Comment: Thank you for your responses!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Mathematica and Matlab are proprietary software systems, so you need to consult the documentation or contact the suppliers for information about the algorithms they use. Sympy is supplied under an open source licence, so you can read the source. If you have a practical interest in the performance of these systems, then I suggest you conduct your own experiments.

Comment: Well, I haven't seen any information regarding the complexity of these systems in their documentation - hence the question. Perhaps running my own experiments does make the most sense.